# Special cases of Ruby array slicing

Tags: arrays, ruby

Document for [`Array#slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) says:

> [A]n empty array is returned when the starting index for an element range is at the end of the array.
>
> Returns nil if the index (or starting index) are out of range.

Having this in mind,

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

a[6,1]   # => nil
a[5,1]   # => []
a[5..10] # => []
```

why does `a[5,1]` and `a[5..10]` return an empty array given that `5` is not the end of the array? It should be out of index, hence it should return `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the lack of a definition for an index being "at the end of the range". For any array `arr`, the index `i` is at the end of the range when `i` equals `arr.size`, that is, when the index equals the index of the last element plus one.

For `a[5,1] #=> []`, `5`, the starting index, is "at the end of the range", since `a.size #=> 5`. Therefore, by the doc, this should return an empty array regardless of the value of the second argument (which is better described as the "size", rather than the "index"). For example,

```
a[5,1]          #=> [] 
a[5, 1_000_000] #=> [] 
a[6,1]          #=> nil
```

For `a[5..10]` we have the same result.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. This only happens when we are slicing the array using range of index am i right? Since a[5] would still return nil

Comment: I think you mean to say "when `i == arr.size`."

Comment: Yes, as `5` is not a range, `a[5]` is the value of `a` at index `5`. `a[i] #=> nil` for all `i >= a.size`.

Comment: Seems odd, given that both a[5], and a[6] return nil, it would make more sense if the ranges of both, ex. a[5,1] and a[6,1] would also return nil

Comment: @s1mpl3, language design decisions are sometimes made for reasons of convenience. Suppose, for example, we have arrays `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = [1,5,3,4,6]` (whose elements are not `nil`) and want an array of indices `i` for which `a[i] == b[i] #=> true`. An easy way of determining that is `a.each_index.with_object([]) { |i,arr| arr << i if a[i] == b[i] } #=> [0, 2]`. Because of the way `[Array#[]]` was designed, we don't have to worry about whether `a` is larger, smaller or the same size as `b`. I expect this definition of `[]` was reached after various use cases had been considered.

Comment: Cary how does you the explains the reason behind the difference and benefit in the range result?

Comment: @s1mpl3, no examples come to mind. Let me think about it. Perhaps other readers can identify coding problems that benefit from the way `Array#[]` is defined when the method has two arguments.

Comment: Oh OK, I agree that a[5] and a[6] both should return nil, but I couldn't see the benefit of a[5,1] and a[6,1] returning different values.

Comment: @s1mpl3, yes, I understand. Thinking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156033/discussion-between-s1mpl3-and-cary-swoveland).